# Is NiTE2 really not supported by qt5?

Tags: qt, nite

I try to initialize nite2 in qt5.2 project(64bit,msvc2012), but it just never succeeded to do that; openni starts just fine everytime. And I looked through the internet, all I found is one post in stackoverflow, saying that NiTE2 is not supported by qt5.2.

Is that true? Someone please comfirms me with that. Thx...

Comment: Figured it out.. It is the problem of Nite 2,2,0,11, using NiTE 2.2.0.10 instead.

Comment: primesense staff compile Nite 2,2,0,11(x64) with still developing openni 2.3 and caused the error.